# Largest n-bit prime

Tags: primes

Is there any tool that I can use to compute the largest 24-bit prime number? I found the largest 16-bit and 32-bit but is there any tool that can take the number of bits as input and compute the largest prime?

Comment: For any reasonable number of bits, I bet you can look it up in this table: http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions/

Comment: Check out the `factor` utility on Linux / Unix.

Comment: any reasonable implementation of `isPrime()` is sufficient for 24 (and 32) bits. The other *"tool"* is the `pow()` function. And the decrement. I'm really tempted to downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

will this do?

```
int largest_24_bit_prime_number() {
    return 16777213;
}
```

Comment: Hmm strange- I found 16777127 (from the list provide at  primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions) to be the largest prime less than 2^24=16777216

Comment: No, it's definitely prime. BTW, I just found a page of numbers you might find useful: http://oeis.org/A014234

Comment: @anupamdas no, the file primes2.txt has " 16777127  16777139  16777141  16777153  16777183  16777199  16777213  16777259" in its 19471st line.